# Cannot SSH on master node in EMR CAWS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, amazon-emr

I´m triying to connect to my master node in my EMR cluster but I get connection timed out, I already do it everything I guess, I create a key pair and set an inbound rule to accept conecctions SSH from my ip, and SSH from everywhere but I can't connect, I check the VPC and check if my cluster is not in a private network and it issn't. I don't know what else can I do. Please any clue?
Thanks.

Comment: What about security group for the master node?

Comment: I already create a security group and create an inbound rule to allow connections from my ip

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned above that you had created a security group to allow SSH to your IP, but is that security group attached to your master node? On the cluster page, under "Security and Access", you'll see the security groups for your master - it should say "More" next to that (arrow in pic), and when you click it you should see a heading for "Additional Groups" with your ssh-allowing security group attached.

[image: security groups for master]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ryan but I check that and still can't connect... I don't know what else could be.

Comment: I really don't know then, should be straightforward. You could dividing up your potential issues by spinning up a t2.nano EC2 instance and trying to connect using SSH with your custom security group. If it fails you know the problem is with your security group, if it works you know there's something broken in your cluster config. Worst comes to worst, you could use the "AWS CLI Export" button, **redact it to remove any personal identifiers**, and post it here if you'd like us to take a look. Best of luck!

Comment: One more thing, have you ever been able to make this ssh key work for connecting to any AWS servers? Might be worth double checking key file permissions, running ssh with verbose output set, to debug.

Comment: Hi Ryan I'm triying to do again but I can't, I create another cluster but this time create a new VPC and attached to the configuration of the cluster and the security groups. In the security groups create inbound rule to allow traffic from my IP and everywhere and check the instance if is in the new VPC and it is. I check the subnet it is public, I don't have any warnings in the cluster and the instances, and I tried to connect again but I still getting connection timed out.I'm doing this from Ecuador, because of that I have to do another configuration or I have to connect trough a VPN?

Answer (score 0):

this is my "AWS CLI Export"`aws emr create-cluster --auto-scaling-role EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole --termination-protected --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Hue Name=Spark --ebs-root-volume-size 10 --ec2-attributes '{"KeyName":"EMR-KeyPairSpark","InstanceProfile":"EMR_EC2_DefaultRole","SubnetId":"subnet-################","EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup":"sg-################","EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup":"##########"}' --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --enable-debugging --release-label emr-5.31.0 --log-uri 's3n://aws-logs-#########-us-east-2/elasticmapreduce/' --name 'clusterDemoSparkR' --instance-groups '[{"InstanceCount":1,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":32,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":2}]},"InstanceGroupType":"MASTER","InstanceType":"m5.xlarge","Name":"Maestro - 1"},{"InstanceCount":1,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":32,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":2}]},"InstanceGroupType":"CORE","InstanceType":"m5.xlarge","Name":"Principal - 2"}]' --scale-down-behavior TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION --region us-east-2`